# How to recover some files from lvm thinpool (from Qubes OS)

Tags: partitioning, encryption, disk, lvm

I mounted, on Ubuntu, a LUKS partition that has these lvm containers from Qubes OS:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvs
  LV                                             VG         Attr       LSize    Pool   Origin                                         Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  pool00                                         qubes_dom0 twi---tz-- <452.86g                                                                                              
  root                                           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz-- <452.86g pool00                                                                                       
  swap                                           qubes_dom0 -wi-a-----    8.96g                                                                                              
  vm-anon-whonix-private                         qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-bitpay-private                              qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-bitpay-private-1604634684-back                                                     
  vm-bitpay-private-1604634684-back              qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-debian-10-private                           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-debian-10-root                              qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-debian-10-root-1604634337-back                                                     
  vm-debian-10-root-1604634337-back              qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-debian-sys-net-private                      qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-debian-sys-net-private-1600569197-back                                             
  vm-debian-sys-net-private-1600569197-back      qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-debian-temp-private                         qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-debian10-coding-private                     qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-debian10-coding-root                        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-debian10-coding-root-1604634103-back                                               
  vm-debian10-coding-root-1604634103-back        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-default-mgmt-dvm-private                    qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-fedora-29-dvm-private                       qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-fedora-29-private                           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-fedora-29-root                              qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-fedora-29-root-1599172317-back                                                     
  vm-fedora-29-root-1599172317-back              qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-hacking-private                             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   20.00g pool00 vm-hacking-private-1602069716-back                                                    
  vm-hacking-private-1602069716-back             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   20.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-multipurpose-private                        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   11.00g pool00 vm-multipurpose-private-1589207893-back                                               
  vm-multipurpose-private-1589207893-back        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   11.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-orwell3-private                             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--  137.00g pool00 vm-orwell3-private-1602465727-back                                                    
  vm-orwell3-private-1602465727-back             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--  137.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-orwell4-private                             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--  117.23g pool00 vm-orwell4-private-1605439750-back                                                    
  vm-orwell4-private-1605439750-back             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--  117.23g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-orwell4-private-snap                        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--  117.23g pool00 vm-orwell4-private                                                                    
  vm-orwell4-root-snap                           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-debian10-coding-root                                                               
  vm-orwell4-volatile                            qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-pcb-design-private                          qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-pcb-design-private-1598425853-back                                                 
  vm-pcb-design-private-1598425853-back          qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-sd-flasher-private                          qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-sd-flasher-private-1596569587-back                                                 
  vm-sd-flasher-private-1596569587-back          qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-social2-private                             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   21.00g pool00 vm-social2-private-1605439747-back                                                    
  vm-social2-private-1605439747-back             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   21.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-social2-private-snap                        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   21.00g pool00 vm-social2-private                                                                    
  vm-social2-root-snap                           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-debian-10-root                                                                     
  vm-social2-volatile                            qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-sys-firewall-private                        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-sys-firewall-private-1588756764-back                                               
  vm-sys-firewall-private-1588756764-back        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-sys-firewall-private-snap                   qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-sys-firewall-private                                                               
  vm-sys-firewall-root-snap                      qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-fedora-29-root-1599172317-back                                                     
  vm-sys-net-private                             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-sys-net-private-1603850959-back                                                    
  vm-sys-net-private-1603850959-back             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-sys-usb-private                             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-sys-usb-private-1605439744-back                                                    
  vm-sys-usb-private-1605439744-back             qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-sys-usb-private-snap                        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-sys-usb-private                                                                    
  vm-sys-usb-root-snap                           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-fedora-29-root                                                                     
  vm-sys-usb-volatile                            qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-sys-whonix-private                          qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-sys-whonix-private-1598482831-back                                                 
  vm-sys-whonix-private-1598482831-back          qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-sysnet-debian10_2-private                   qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-sysnet-debian10_2-private-1605439757-back                                          
  vm-sysnet-debian10_2-private-1605439757-back   qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-sysnet-debian10_2-private-snap              qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-sysnet-debian10_2-private                                                          
  vm-sysnet-debian10_2-root                      qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-sysnet-debian10_2-root-1605439757-back                                             
  vm-sysnet-debian10_2-root-1605439757-back      qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-sysnet-debian10_2-root-snap                 qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-sysnet-debian10_2-root                                                             
  vm-sysnet-debian10_2-volatile                  qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-temp-private                                qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-temp-private-1595675857-back                                                       
  vm-temp-private-1595675857-back                qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-unsafe_code-private                         qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   78.00g pool00 vm-unsafe_code-private-1605379428-back                                                
  vm-unsafe_code-private-1605379428-back         qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   78.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-whonix-gw-14-private                        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-whonix-gw-14-root                           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-whonix-gw-14-root-1571185748-back                                                  
  vm-whonix-gw-14-root-1571185748-back           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-whonix-ws-14-dvm-private                    qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-whonix-ws-14-private                        qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-whonix-ws-14-root                           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00 vm-whonix-ws-14-root-1571185609-back                                                  
  vm-whonix-ws-14-root-1571185609-back           qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   10.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-win10_unsafe_coding-private                 qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-win10_unsafe_coding-private-1602769589-back                                        
  vm-win10_unsafe_coding-private-1602769589-back qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-win10_unsafe_coding-root                    qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   90.00g pool00 vm-win10_unsafe_coding-root-1602769589-back                                           
  vm-win10_unsafe_coding-root-1602769589-back    qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--   90.00g pool00                                                                                       
  vm-zoom2-private                               qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00 vm-zoom2-private-1599067205-back                                                      
  vm-zoom2-private-1599067205-back               qubes_dom0 Vwi---tz--    2.00g pool00
```

Something is wrong and I want to recover only the vm-orwell4-* containers. At least copy some files from it. I know nothing about lvm thinpool.

I tried

```
sudo lvchange -ay -v qubes_dom0/vm-orwell4-private
  Activating logical volume qubes_dom0/vm-orwell4-private.
  activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for qubes_dom0/vm-orwell4-private.
  Creating qubes_dom0-pool00_tmeta
  Loading table for qubes_dom0-pool00_tmeta (253:2).
  Resuming qubes_dom0-pool00_tmeta (253:2).
  Creating qubes_dom0-pool00_tdata
  Loading table for qubes_dom0-pool00_tdata (253:3).
  Resuming qubes_dom0-pool00_tdata (253:3).
  Executing: /usr/sbin/thin_check -q --clear-needs-check-flag /dev/mapper/qubes_dom0-pool00_tmeta
  /usr/sbin/thin_check failed: 1
  Check of pool qubes_dom0/pool00 failed (status:1). Manual repair required!
  Removing qubes_dom0-pool00_tdata (253:3)
  Removing qubes_dom0-pool00_tmeta (253:2)
```

Also tried

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgchange -ay
  Check of pool qubes_dom0/pool00 failed (status:1). Manual repair required!
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "qubes_dom0" now active
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's the output of what I tried after looking into https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351921/lvm-how-to-recover-lvm-thin-pool-volume-after-failed-repair

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvchange -an qubes_dom0 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvchange -pr -ay qubes_dom0/pool00_tmeta
  Operation not permitted on hidden LV qubes_dom0/pool00_tmeta.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo  lvs -a --units m | grep pool00_tmeta   lvs -a --units m | grep pool00_tmeta  ^C
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo  lvs -a --units m | grep pool00_tmeta  
  [pool00_tmeta]                                 qubes_dom0 ewi-------    116.00m                                                                                              
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvcreate -L 256M -n pool00R qubes_dom0
  Logical Volume "pool00R" already exists in volume group "qubes_dom0"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvchange -ay qubes_dom0/poool00R    
  Failed to find logical volume "qubes_dom0/poool00R"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvchange -ay qubes_dom0/poool00R
  Failed to find logical volume "qubes_dom0/poool00R"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo thin_repair -i /dev/qubes_dom0/pool00_tmeta -o /dev/qubes_dom0/pool00R
Output file does not exist.
 
The output file should either be a block device,
or an existing file.  The file needs to be large
enough to hold the metadata.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ # what? /dev/qubes_dom0 does not even exist
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo thin_check /dev/qubes_dom0/pool00R
Couldn't stat path
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: The `pool00R` would need to be a block device rather than a file. That said, you may be able to do a repair with a `thin_dump` like this ⇢ `sudo thin_dump --repair /dev/qubes_dom0/pool00_tmeta > pool_meta.xml`. Once the file has been generated, you can import it against the existing pool with: `sudo thin_restore -i pool00_tmeta.xml -o /dev/qubes_dom0/pool00_tmeta`. By dumping into a readable file, you'll also have the opportunity to check things over before importing over the existing `pool00_tmeta` metadata.

Comment: @Matigo hwo can I convert to a block device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you executed the command

`sudo lvcreate -L 256M -n pool00R qubes_dom0`

you created a logical volume called **pool00R**.

With this command

`sudo lvchange -ay qubes_dom0/poool00R`

you were trying to activate a logical volume called **poool00R** (notice the extra "o"), which does not exist.

---

As the author of the [Unix StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351921/lvm-how-to-recover-lvm-thin-pool-volume-after-failed-repair/556628#556628) where that typo was in the first place I can do nothing but to give you my deepest apologies: that extra "o" appeared invisible to me as well. I am incredibly sorry for finding it out this late.